# Opening Dot File with OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I need to work on opening a DOT (word document template) file, replace the fillers and save it as Document file.

On opening DOT file I am getting "Document File is Corrupted".

Is it possible to work with DOT file using OpenXML.

**UPDATE:** I am saving DOT file as XML (manually using "Save as.."). Renaming file back to dot, so it is XML file built on WordML. Still trying to open it through OpenXML giving me the same error.

Comment: Which version of Word? a .dot file isn't XML based but a .dotx is. However, it's not ascii though.

Comment: I am working on Word 2003. I noticed this thing and I saved the dot as XML and renamed it back to ".dot". It's still the same error.

Comment: Okay please permit me to rant. The DOTX file format is one of the downright ugliest, snarkiest, holier-than-thou, "we're Microsoft and we know what the heck we're doing" examples of a file format gone horribly wrong that exists in the known universe. The alien hackers onboard the Independence Day mother ship produce better XML than the crufty, proprietary, poisonous mix of quasi-XML that the overpriced Microsoft Office suite hacks together in a desperate bid to appear "open" while actually forcing yet another proprietary clusterfrak of Redmond nerd minutiae on users who honestly deserve better

Comment: aaanyway, how are you opening the dot file, using interop or...?

Comment: haha... I agree with you Swingline. I practically impossible to make anything out of that confounded XML, though I am stuck with it, as with many other developers...

Comment: @SWeko: No I am trying to save dot file as XML (manually convert once) and then use OpenXML to manipulate it and save as Document file.

Comment: @Swingline: I can't quite see what you're getting at there. Is it that DOTX files are a bit rubbish? ;-)

Comment: try renaming it to .dotx, or if it's a client application, using interop (it sucks, but it gets the job done).

Comment: OpenXML is used in the new formats of Office 2007 (.dotx and .docx)
WordML is a bit older and cannot be used with the OpenXML libraries.

Comment: @SWeko: changing extension is not helping.
@Zippy: I guess it makes sense. I was assuming it will work with dot in XML format. I am trying it with Dotx and it seems to work. Let me see try converting Dot to dotx and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Zippy: could you post your comment as answer, so that I can close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXML is used in the new formats of Office 2007 (.dotx and .docx).
WordML is a bit older and cannot be used with the OpenXML libraries.

You can load a WordML file as an XmlDocument or load it into a string if you know exactly what data you want to replace.