# Do we need Office Installation to work with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

I am working with OpenXML manipulating the document.

Do we need to have office installed for opening document through OpenXML?

Comment: one thing interesting I note, your ID is similar to your question and if you post another question then you make another ID :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. You only need to have a reference to the library that provides all the OpenXML functionality. That library is not dependant on Office.

Comment: Thanks Zippy, I thought so, I am struggling to open a DOT file with OpenXML so just wanted to make sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014792/opening-dot-file-with-openxml

Comment: OpenXML will only handle the new file formats, not the old DOC and DOT. Your issue may be that you are trying to opne a file that uses the old binary format.