# My program is using office integrations and targetting windows without MS Office, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-office

I have developped a program (C shrap) which help schools in archiving there documents, in the program, I am using Microsoft Word, Excel and Access integrations, But I dont know if the target PC will have MS office, so, is there a way to target these PCs without requesting MS office installed?
My references:
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.word

Comment: The Interop libraries don't replace the Office apps. If your app needs to interact with Office (opening files, modifying) then you need Office installed. If you just need to move, copy files around then you don't need Office.

Comment: I agree, it depends specifically what kind of functionality you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Interop then you need office install.

I suggest instead using other libraries which don't need Office, such as the openxml sdk.

You can find various examples online on how to do this.  Here are a few

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/11047/edit-word-documents-using-openxml-and-c-without-automationinterop

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87711/Manipulate-Docx-with-C-without-Microsoft-Word-inst

[Do we need Office Installation to work with OpenXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015272/do-we-need-office-installation-to-work-with-openxml/3015297)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

Comment: "If you use Interop then you need office install."...not always. It depends exactly what functionality is needed - see the comment on the main thread above. For a few things you can get away with just using the DLLs. And I agree that, for some jobs, the newer SDKs to interact with the openXML files directly are a better solution. But they're not a solution if you literally want to automate a running Office instance. OP didn't really make clear specifically what functionality is required, so I'd say the question is not fully answerable at the moment.